# NSTextAlignmentCenter not work with custom text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I was subclassing `UITextField` to make my custom text field.

I used `self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;` to set the text alignment, but when I began editing, the cursor's initial position was left rather than exactly the center. Hoever, when I entered something, the text was in the center position.

`textRectForBounds:` and `editingRectForBounds:` all return the same `CGRect` value.

Here is the code:

```
@interface MyTextfield () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    return self;
}
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return  CGRectInset(bounds, 20.5, 4.5);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return  CGRectInset(bounds, 20.5, 4.5);
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Do some animation
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Do some animation
}
```

What's the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where you have written the code of alignment? can you show your custom textField class?

Comment: I set the alignment in the `initWithFrame:`.

Comment: can you please add your code here if possible..

Answer (score 0):

first of all create one UITextField class.

CustomTextfield.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTextfield : UITextField
@end
```

CustomTextfield.m

```
#import "CustomTextfield.h"
@interface CustomTextfield () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation CustomTextfield
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        self.placeholder = @"Test";
        self.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        self.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }

    return self;
}
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return  CGRectInset(bounds, 20.5, 4.5);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return  CGRectInset(bounds, 20.5, 4.5);
}
```

Now use CustomTextfield class to your view controller like this.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UITextField *txtEmailfield = [[CustomTextfield alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
    txtEmailfield.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:txtEmailfield];
}
```

Note : In this view controller please add this in @interface yourviewcontroller name () **`<UITextFieldDelegate>`**

Comment: not works for me. By the way, I am not quite understand why you set the delegate to self, then set the delegate to view controller again.

Comment: oh! i am sorry i just copy paste to my current code that's why may be that is in there..   now tell me you have create custom textfield as programmtically or Drag and drop to controller...

Comment: so can you please try my code wise what i have added. if possible. i am already test this and this is work good in my side...

Comment: I have updated my code, I have set the delegate to self in the implement of my custom text field. So if I set the delegate to view controller, my animation  code will not work.